# How to know if the cache in doctrine 2 + zend framewrok is working?

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Here is my configuration for the cache in a doctrine 2 + zend framewrok 2 project :
module.config.php :

```
 // Doctrine config
    'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'   => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity'),
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                ),
            )
        ),
        'configuration' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'metadata_cache'    => 'mycache',
                'query_cache'       => 'mycache',
                'result_cache'      => 'mycache',
            )
        )
    ),

    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
            'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory', 
        // fin  la partie ajouté pour le cache doctrine 2 
             'doctrine.cache.mycache' => function ($sm) {
            $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache();
            $memcache = new \Memcache();
            $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
            $cache->setMemcache($memcache);
            return $cache;
        },
        ),
    ),
```

I have no error , but i need to know if the cache is working or not ? how this can be done ?
thanks.

Comment: Install something like this and you'll see what happens in your memcache :) https://code.google.com/p/phpmemcacheadmin/

Comment: how to use it in windows / wamp ?

Comment: i'm talking about the phpmemcacheadmin not about memcache , and thanks i can do that alone.

Comment: what's the difference for phpmemcacheadmin where to work, on windows or on linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check integration between ZF and Doctrine Cache, you can change cache configuration to use filesystem adapter and check files in `data` folder:

```
'configuration' => array(
    'orm_default' => array(
        'metadata_cache'    => 'filesystem',
        'query_cache'       => 'filesystem',
        'result_cache'      => 'filesystem',
    )
)
```

And if you need to check if data were written into memcache, you can use telnet API:

Connect:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
```

List all items:

```
stats items
```

Comment: @Iku can i ask for more clarifications about how the cache file_system works exactly ? i mean : is it automaticaly that doctrine goes and look for if the cache exists if yes use it ? or do i need to do that in my doctrine queries ?? plz waiting for your answers... thanks –

Comment: @user3911183 Looks like you talk about result cache. It is not fully automatic, you need to call useResultCache method (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache) on every query you want to cache.
And `filesystem` is only cache driver which saves data to files.

Comment: actualy i'm talking about the boths , in the configuration ; it's noted query_cache and result_cache ; so there is files for query ( talking here about the transformation of a doctrine query into mysql query ) and others for result ? i am wrong ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Query cache is used to cache SQL transformation from DQL. And result cache is used to cache query results - so there is no need to query database or hydrate data again after first query.

Comment: i have an other question if you permit , what is the difference between the cache using file_system and the cache using memcache in terme of performance ?

Comment: That's tricky question :) Performance mostly depends on architecture, basic difference is: file system is (mostly) local, memcache is accessed over a network (TCP/IP connection), so file system cache could be sometimes faster. I recommend you these two articles for further information: http://www.percona.com/blog/2006/08/09/cache-performance-comparison/ and http://surniaulula.com/2012/12/04/memcached-vs-disk-cache/

Comment: @Iku , plz iku can u help me out here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762283/how-to-use-the-cache-in-doctrine-2-and-zend-framework-2?

Comment: @user3911183 sure, check my answer, hope it helps