# How to use the cache in doctrine 2 and zend framework 2?

Tags: php, caching, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

plz i need some help here  , i've goolged a lot but without result :/
how can i exploit the query and their result stored in the memcache , i'm working with zend framework 2 and doctrine 2 ? and here is my configuration in module.config.php :

```
 // Doctrine config
     'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                ),
        )
            ),
            /***** enabling the memcache ****/
            'configuration' => array(
                'orm_default' => array(
                    'metadata_cache'    => 'mycache',
                    'query_cache'       => 'mycache',
                    'result_cache'      => 'mycache',

            )
            /**** end ****/
        )
    ),

    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
            'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
            'doctrine.cache.mycache' => function ($sm) {
                 $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache();
                 $memcache = new \Memcache();
                 $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
                 $cache->setMemcache($memcache);
                 return $cache;
         },
        ),
    ),
```

any idea or link is appeciated , thanks.
Regards.

Comment: Is "mycache" a custom caching created by you?

Comment: no , i'm enabling the memcache for storing query and result 's doctrine queries , but i still enable to use it ? i'm looking for how can i save the queries and how get the result ...

Comment: In "enabling the memcache" of your example, you are using mycache as value to the 3 caching types of Doctrine. What is this mycache doing in your code and which code does it invoke?

Comment: the "mycache" is a an object for memcache which i anstancied, and which i use for the three type ...

Comment: Okay, that's important information. Please show the mycache code, log files of a doctrine query that shows any debug or maybe error information and look if there's eventually a php error. Does the other Doctrina caching classes work? How do the config for the caching looks like?

Comment: where am i supposed to find the error ? what i did is o check if the doctrine cache data is really created , and yes , i can show it using a function for showing the content of memcache ... if i didn't answer your question plz clarify it ! thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose You are using [DoctrineModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule), right?
Change your configuration to this:

```php
// Doctrine config
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
            ),
        ),
    ),
    /***** enabling the memcache ****/
    'configuration' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'metadata_cache'    => 'memcache',
            'query_cache'       => 'memcache',
            'result_cache'      => 'memcache',
        )
    ),
    /**** end ****/
    'cache' => array(
        'memcache' => array(
            'instance' => 'doctrine.cache.mycache',
        ),
    ),
),

'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'doctrine.cache.mycache' => function ($sm) {
            $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache();
            $memcache = new \Memcache();
            $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
            $cache->setMemcache($memcache);
            return $cache;
        },
    ),
),
```

How does this work?

In module configuration are predefined configurations for every supported cache adapter, [including memcache](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/config/module.config.php#L36). With this configuration, you are saying "use memcache for caching":

```php
'configuration' => array(
    'orm_default' => array(
        'metadata_cache'    => 'memcache',
        'query_cache'       => 'memcache',
        'result_cache'      => 'memcache',
    )
),
```

This cache needs configured Memcache instance and this config saying "Memcache instance is available in ServiceManager with key 'doctrine.cache.mycache'"

```php
'cache' => array(
    'memcache' => array(
        'instance' => 'doctrine.cache.mycache',
    ),
),
```

Update:

How to use result cache ([documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html)):

```php
$cache = $entityManager->getConfiguration()->getResultCacheImpl();
$cacheItemKey = 'my-item';

// test if item exists in the cache
if ($cache->contains($cacheItemKey)) {
    $item = $cache->fetch($cacheItemKey); // retrieve item from cache
} else {
    $item = $repository->find($id); // retrieve item from repository
    $cache->save($cacheItemKey, $item); // save item to cache
}
```

Comment: thanks Iku for your answer , what i need exactly is : how to enable the cache in my controllers to get the result from the memcache ? i guess i didn't explain well my problematic .

Comment: back for a question plz , enabling the cache in doctrine automaticaly stores every query and every result in  the cache ? thanks in advance !

Comment: @user3911183 For query cache it is true, once query cache is activated, it caches alle DQL transformations automatically. On the contrary, result cache needs to be activated by hand - see documantation: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache